# match a string over array field in doctrine odm

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have a field short name i.e type of collection in doctrine object document manager(odm) and I have a string. I want to match that string over that short name field to collect the matching results. I am using find by with the pattern given below to get it but the result is an empty array.

```
$result = $dm->getRepository('a')
     ->findBy(['name' => new \MongoRegex("/.*".$partialText .".*/i"),
      'shortName' => new \MongoRegex("/.*".$partialText .".*/i")], [], $limit, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below input data in a document:

```
"CrTime" : "20170620123601"
"CrTime" : "20170622071138"
"CrTime" : "20170622131845"
"CrTime" : "20160612131845"
```

Now i want to match only dates in 2016. From mongodb commandLine

```
db.getCollection('name').find({ "parent.CrTime" : { "$regex" : "2016.*"}});
```

From a java driver view:

```
Clause2.put("parent.CrTime", new BasicDBObject("$regex", "2016.*"));
```

You can use `$regex` to get the data

Comment: Its working on mongodb shell but I want to use it from doctrine's find by method or i can use query builder for that, so can you help me to solve it @voldy ?

Comment: I tried this using both mongoDB cmd and java-mongo driver. Debug the dbObject which will contain the find() query your code sends to mongo. Check if you are generating the desired query